# custom event not getting fired in Angular

Tags: angular, events, eventhandler

I want to find if the element in a list are within the viewport or not.
For this i want to create a custom event and call a method in it.
The event is not working.

Below is what i have attempted:

component.html

```
<div #myEl id="myEl_{{item.id}}" (inViewport)="onScreen($event,myEl)" *ngIf="!item.question" class="card panel m-b-" style="height:auto;">
```

**inViewport** is my custom event.

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.css']
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Output() inViewport: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

 onScreen(event:any,selector) {

    var test = this.getElementOnScreen(selector);
    if (test)
      console.log(selector.id + " IS VISIBLE");
  }
}
```

Now this onScreen is not getting called.
I might have missed out something.

Please guide!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the selector of the component `app-item`

```
<app-item #myEl id="myEl_{{item.id}}" (inViewport)="onScreen($event,myEl)" *ngIf="!item.question" class="card panel m-b-" style="height:auto;">
```

Comment: Cant i create an event and use it on the component elements?

Comment: You should be having it as an attribute and have the selector as a attribute selector

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { Component, Input, AfterViewInit, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-item',
      template: '<div #myEl id="myEl_{{item.id}}" *ngIf="!item.question" class="card panel m-b-" style="height:auto;">
',
      styleUrls: ['./item.component.css']
    })
    export class ItemComponent implements AfterViewInit {
      @Output() inViewport: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

      ngAfterViewInit() {
         console.log(selector.id + " IS VISIBLE");
         this.inViewport.emit(); 
      }
    }
```